# JScrollPane in JPanel added to JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, scrollbar, gridbaglayout

I'm currently trying to get into build GUIs with the GridBagLayout in Swift.

When trying to make a GUI for a project I'm working on I ran into a problem:

When creating a list of things, the Panel exceeds my screen height, so I set the frame's preferred Size to 900 pixels.

However, the list exceeds 900 pixels in height. So I Tried adding a JScrollPane to the Panel that conaints the list. There just isn't one.

My Frame architecture is something like this:
Frame f -> JTabbedPane Wrapper -> JPanel p

I tied applying a ScrollPane to either one of those Objects, none worked. Any tips?

Comment: *"So I Tried adding a JScrollPane to the Panel that conaints the list."* - You have to set the panel as the content of the `JScrollPane` and not add it inside of the panel. One of the ways to do this is directly in the constructor: `new JScrollPane(panel);`. If I understood that wrong and this is not the problem, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Either you should use an appropriate [layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) which can compute the required panel width, or you should set the preferred size for your panel. Something like `panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 2000));`

Comment: @lukas-rotter, adding the Panel to the ScrollPane is exactly what I did. new JScrollPane(Wrapper); or new JScrollPane(f);

Answer (score 0):

So, I just want to let you know, I'm new to Java and just noticed my mistake.

In the function that created the JPanel, I still returned the JPanel instead of the ScrollPane.

Anways, thanks for helping everyone.